# implementing own class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, iterator

Please help me implement class `Repeat` and it's methods:

```
class Repeat 
  def initialize(n) 
    #TODO 
  end 

  def each  
    #TODO 
  end 
end 

def n_times(n)
  #TODO 
end
```

This piece of code:

```
n_times(2) { |count| puts "You called me #{count} times" }
```

should return this result:

```
# You called me 1 times 
# You called me 2 times
```

Comment: Great question. I got you.

Comment: `Repeat`, `new`, and `each` do not appear anywhere in the calling script.

Comment: `n_times` isn't part of the class `Repeat`. It's unclear how your problem is defined.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow.  It seems like you are new to OOP and passing a block to a method in Ruby.  This answer simplifies your question and just focuses on passing a block to a method.  Here is some functioning code:

```
def n_times(n, &block)
  n.times do |counter|
    yield(counter + 1)
  end
end

n_times(2) { |count| puts "You called me #{count} times" }
```